# Apple Pay with Recurly in ionic iOS application

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, applepay, recurly, applepayjs

I understand this SDK https://github.com/recurly/recurly-client-ios/ is exclusive for native iOS, What if we have to implement Apple pay with recurly in an ionic application? Please guide if we could follow the Apple Pay with web https://docs.recurly.com/docs/apple-pay-on-the-web implementation in an ionic cordova app  or should we integrate apple pay SDK in ionic like this https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/apple-pay/

Comment: The plugin is very old (6 years), you should try: https://www.npmjs.com/package/capacitor-apple-pay